# OpenGL – Severe distortions even with correct matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, opengl-es, glsl, sdl

My simple OpenGL program is displaying a very severely distorted shape. I'm using GLM for matrix math. I compared the modelView matrix and the projection matrix values to another program that it displaying the values correctly. Yet, it is still distorted. What could be the cause? Here is the matrix code:

```
modelViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(3.0f, 5.0f, 7.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), (float)height/(float)width, 0.01f, 100.0f);
```

And here is the vertex shader code:

```
#version 300 es

in mediump vec3 vertexPosition;
uniform mediump mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mediump mat4 projectionMatrix;

out vec3 finalPosition;

void main(void) {

gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);

}
```

Here are screenshots of an (unlit) cuboid:

[image: Distorted image]
[image: Correct image with the same matrix values and the same shader]

Note that the correct image is the black one. They are both using the exact same shader and the same model view and projection matrix numbers. Why is this happening?

Comment: The reason may be, that you forgot to use a fragment shader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the question by changing the glViewport parameters. Apparently the view transformation was done incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the aspect ratio is being calculated incorrectly - it should be width / height.

You currently have:

```
projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 
                   (float)height/(float)width, 0.01f, 100.0f);
```

Try replacing this with:

```
projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), 
                   (float)width/(float)height, 0.01f, 100.0f);
```

Comment: I adjusted it. It became even more distorted. Remember that I am using a 16:9 screen in landscape.

Comment: Ah, OK. If that's not the problem, I think you might need to post more of your code - there doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong with the bit you posted.

Comment: Never mind. I found the issue. It turns out that I added wrong parameters to glViewport(). That's why the viewport transformation was done incorrectly. I didn't consider that stage when my pictures were deformed. Thanks for your time anyways.

Comment: @user3894009 You need to either delete your question, or answer your question yourself and accept the answer.